# Proof n is semi-prime using Pollard-rho

Tags: number-theory, semiprimes

I wrote some code determining whether a number n is square free, and decided I want to make it as fast as I can. A number that isn't square free is either a square or the product of at least three primes, so we only need to check whether n is divisible by p for $p ≤ n^{1/3}$, which can be done in $O(n^{1/3})$ or in $O(n^{1/3} / \ln n)$ if we have a table of primes, plus one check whether n is square.

Then I thought I could find large prime factors using Pollard-rho. Pollard rho finds a prime factor p in $O(\sqrt p)$. It will find the smallest prime factor of a number with three prime factors in $O(n^{1/6})$. The problem: What if n is square free?

We can run say $5 \cdot n^{1/6}$ rounds of Pollard-rho and if no factor is found, then we suspect or suspect strongly that n doesn't have three prime factors. We can test quickly that n is not a prime and not the square of some number. At this point, to prove that n is square free we have to prove that it is not semi-prime.

One idea is a probabilistic test: We run Pollard-rho for $c \cdot n^{1/6}$ rounds, and if c is large enough then we can argue that n is a probabilistic semiprime, otherwise the smallest of three or more factors would have been found. Has anyone checked for which c we can use that argument?

The other question is obviously whether there is any other method to test whether n can be proven to be semiprime if it is semiprime. If it isn't semiprime then either Miller-Rabin will show very quickly that it is very probable prime, and Pollard-rho will be very likely to find one of three or more factors.

Note that a very similar question (is n a semiprime) has been closed by pointing to answers trying to find factors. Which is obviously not answering either question at all.

Comment: Please link to the "very similar question"

Comment: "At this point, to prove that $n$ is square free we have to prove that it is not semi-prime." Why is that? A semiprime that isn't a square is square-free. (Also, please link to the "very similar question".)

Comment: I noticed a long time ago that a number was constructed for which is known that it is semiprime but the factors are unknown. Elliptic curves were used. If this works in general , no idea. But determining whether a number is squarefree is in general not easier than to factor it.

Comment: But if you find out all small prime factors (ECM is much faster than Pollard-Rho and much more reliable , Pollard-Rho might fail to find a factor!) and can be sure that no prime factor , say , below $10^9$ is missing and the partial factorization indicates a squarefree number , then the number is very likely squarefree.